# UIImageview won't update after changing the center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to create a small augmented reality application where I move an image on top of the camera capture. So the only thing I change is the center of the UIImageview:

```
[imageView1 setCenter:CGPointMake(x-16, 240)];
```

and the center gets updated but the position of the image on the screen stays the same.

after the center update, this gets called:

```
[self.imageView1 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:testImage waitUntilDone:YES];
```

The funny thing is that in the first iteration it actually updates the position. But only the first time. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to comment it but still no answer ? i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
imageView1.center = CGPointMake(imageView1.center.x-16, 240);
```

Comment: x is not a coordinate, it's a double value calculated in every iteration. I should've written that in the original post. But anyway, when I write the center coordinates in the console everything is OK. So I am guessing it's a display problem of some sort.

Comment: is there a way to refresh an imageview? I tried with          [imageView1 setNeedsDisplay];  but this doesn't seem to work....

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer in this post ([UIImageView not responding to centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711221/uiimageview-not-responding-to-centering?rq=1)) suggests that the problem is autolayout, which makes sense.

This post ([Can I disable autolayout for a specific subview at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368440/can-i-disable-autolayout-for-a-specific-subview-at-runtime)) explains how to disable autolayout for specific elements.

Another answer suggest you add constraints (for x and y), create IBOutlets for these constrataints and update those to move the UI-element.