# CGRectMake doesn't work for custom frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, interface-builder, autolayout

This is the code I'm using:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (screenSize.height <= 480.0f) {
        self.img.frame = CGRectMake(21, 20, 280, 275);
        self.text.frame = CGRectMake(21, 20, 280, 275);
        self.decrease.frame= CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
        self.add.frame = CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
        self.increase.frame =CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
    }
    else{
        self.img.frame = CGRectMake(21, 20, 280, 400);
        self.text.frame = CGRectMake(21, 20, 280, 400);
        self.decrease.frame= CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
        self.add.frame = CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
    }    
}
```

I'm using the same code (outside of the viewDidLayoutSubviews) to alter the frames and it works perfectly. 
My problem is that the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews doesn't work. It doesn't alter the frames sizes or positions upon loading the view. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure, but you can't reframe your view once it is created and loaded.

Comment: I don't get it, I use the same code to animate the height of the "text" UITextView for instance.

Comment: Could you edit your post to show how you execute viewDidLayoutSubviews, because it looks like it isn't being called. You should also put an NSLog or printF or breakpoint in there to make sure that it definitely is.

Comment: I just use it as it is, it might be a novice mistake, I don't know how  else it should be executed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15242064/1827583  This is what works for me at the moment;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you call the [super viewDidLayoutSubviews] first?

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{ 
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (screenSize.height <= 480.0f) {
        self.img.frame = CGRectMake(21, 20, 280, 275);
        self.text.frame = CGRectMake(21, 20, 280, 275);
        self.decrease.frame= CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
        self.add.frame = CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
        self.increase.frame =CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
    }
    else{
        self.img.frame = CGRectMake(21, 20, 280, 400);
        self.text.frame = CGRectMake(21, 20, 280, 400);
        self.decrease.frame= CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
        self.add.frame = CGRectMake(55, 308, 39, 39);
    }    
}
```

Comment: This does nothing. From the docs: "The default implementation of this method does nothing."