# Create array of UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to insert a UILabel into an array and then display it in a certain point on the screen. Using a for loop, I'm counting the amount of elements in a array, and for every element, I want to create a label. This is only producing one label at the moment (the first element in the array).

```
 int y = 260;

for(int i = 0; i < _jsonArray.count; i ++)
{
    NSNumber *one = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"amount"];
    NSString *name = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];


    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 200, 40)];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myLabel setText:name];
    [_slices addObject:one];
    [[self view] addSubview:myLabel];
    y=y+20;

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you used the debugger to single-step through your code and verified that there is more than 1 element in the array?

Comment: Yeah I have a pie chart (XYPieChart) that is displaying all the elements from the array

Comment: Well your code looks correct, so my next guess would be when you add the `UILabel` to the view it is either falling outside of the view's bounds or being obscured by something else.  I presume this is just 'test' code, as a `UITableView` would be a better solution

Comment: what is the result already of this code?

Comment: incidentally, you aren't actually storing the `UILabel` in an array anywhere...

Comment: I suspect you're stacking the labels on top of each other, possibly due to auto-layout.

Comment: I think I see where this is going wrong. Each label created is called "myLabel". Therefore, when I set the text of "myLabel" it is going to change all the labels. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Any idea how to solve auto layout?

Comment: Maybe you can try using tags based on the index of the array

Comment: @SamStone myLabel is scoped inside of the loop, so it's a "new" myLabel every time through. The instance will be retained by the view you're adding it to.  So, no, you're not setting the text of the same label each time.

Comment: Ah, got you mharper. Maybe it is the auto layout thing then, but I'm not sure how when I add 20 to 'y' after each loop.

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11730666/128317

Comment: Thank you very much mharper. Worked a charm. If you want to post an answer I'll mark you correct?

Comment: As an aside, you are apparently creating a label with a height of 40, and incrementing the Y coordinate for each subsequent label by only 20.  Consequently, even when this does work, the labels will overlap each other.

Comment: I can't take credit for simply pointing you to someone else's answer.  Glad you're unstuck!

Comment: Thanks. I was going to fiddle with those values once I had this bit nailed.

Comment: use IBOutletCollection to get array of labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make arrayLabels a property so you can access for anywhere in your view controller

```
  _arrayLabels = [NSMutableArray array];
  int y = 260;

  for(int i = 0; i < _jsonArray.count; i ++)
  {
    NSNumber *one = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"amount"];
    NSString *name = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];


    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 200, 40)];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myLabel setText:name];
    [_slices addObject:one];
    [[self view] addSubview:myLabel];
    [_arrayLabels addObject:myLabel];
    y=y+20;
  }
```

then you can obtain the label with `(UILabel *)[_arrayLabels objectAtIndex:i];`

Comment: While your answer addresses the question in the title, it doesn't address the problem stated in the body - only one label is visible

Comment: Hi. This would actually help me, but I'm getting errors "Use of undeclared identifier". Any ideas?

EDIT. Solved that error (create array in header file). But now I get an error on the "addObject" line.

Here is what I put in my header file:

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *arrayLabels;

Comment: Make sure that in your .h file add 
`@property NSMutableArray *arrayLabels;`

Comment: Declare it as an `NSMutableArray`

Comment: This may be a cheeky, but could you explain why the "(retain, nonatomic)" was not needed here?

Thank you btw!

Comment: I put that as fast as i could, did you try with 
`@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSMutableArray *arrayLabels;`