# UILabel stops animations

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview, uitextfield

I have 5 `UIImageViews` getting animated down the screen. If one is pressed, and it meets the requirements, it will add 1 to your score, using this:

```
self.score.text = @(self.score.text.integerValue + 1).stringValue;
```

But when the text in the `UILabel` updates, all the animations stop abruptly and the remaining `UIImageViews` disappear. But, the animation only restarts after a few seconds, as if the images are becoming hidden. The code to animate the images and change image(They are the same for each one):

```
- (void) squareOneMover {
    NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(3);
    [self.squareOne setHidden:NO];
    CGPoint originalPosition = self.squareOne.center;
    CGPoint position = self.squareOne.center;
    originalPosition.y = -55;
    position.y += 790;
    [self.squareOne setCenter:originalPosition];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:r + 3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         [self.squareOne setCenter:position];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL complete) {
                         if (complete) {
                             [self squareOneColour];
                             [self squareOneMover];
                         }
                     }
    ];
}

- (void) squareOneColour {
    NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(5);
    [self.squareOne setImage:[self.colorArray objectAtIndex:r]];
}
```

Anyone have a solution? And if by changing the text in a `UILabel` is supposed to stop animations (I don't know why they would do so) can someone provide a workaround to make keeping score possible.

Edit: I created a button that would increase the integer value of `score`. This means I can change the text in the `UILabel` manually. The animations still stopped the moment the text changed.

Edit 2: Method for the pressed event:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    NSUInteger a = [self.colorArray indexOfObject:self.squareOne.image];
    NSUInteger b = [self.iconColorArray indexOfObject:self.icon.image];
    if ([self.squareOne.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation]) {
        _squareOne.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (a!=b) {
        if (self.squareOne.hidden==YES) {
            NSLog(@"NO");
            }
        }
    if (a==b) {
        if ([self.squareOne.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation]) {
            self.score.text = @(self.score.text.integerValue + 1).stringValue;
        }
    }

    if ([self.squareTwo.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation]) {
        _squareTwo.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Looking at Matt's answer, how would I animate the `UIImageView` by "changing its constraints"?

Constraints:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-25-[btn1]-25-[btn2(==btn1)]-25-[btn3(==btn1)]-25-[btn4(==btn1)]-25-[btn5(==btn1)]-25-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint 
      constraintWithItem:self.squareOne 
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                  toItem:self.view 
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
              multiplier:0.0 
                constant:-55.0]];
```

Comment: I think the problem lays in the pressed event. Can you show us the method for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //what all are you checking with the if's? 

 //I'm just curious there's a lot going on here

**//if this evaluates true
if ([self.squareOne.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation]) {
    _squareOne.hidden = YES;
}**
if (a!=b) {
    if (self.squareOne.hidden==YES) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
        }
    }
if (a==b) {
    **          //this will evaluate true also
    if ([self.squareOne.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation]) {
        self.score.text = @(self.score.text.integerValue + 1).stringValue;
    }**
}

//this works fine even when I added everything from interface builder which almost never happens
```

**Update**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic)UILabel *label;
@property int tapCount;
@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void)viewDidLoad{

     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
    [tap addTarget:self action:@selector(userTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


}
-(UILabel*)label{

    if (!_label) {
        _label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        _label.text = @"taps:%3i",0;
        [_label sizeToFit];
        _label.center = self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:_label];
    }

    return _label;
}

-(void)userTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    NSLog(@"tap");
 self.tapCount ++;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{
                        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"taps:%i",self.tapCount];
                        self.label.center = [sender locationInView:self.view];

                    }
                     completion:nil];

}



@end
```

**just cleaning up the code a bit for future onlookers **
direct copy and paste only delete everything inside ViewController.m
on a new project and paste this in it's place

Comment: Don't worry about the if statements. I like Matt's answer, so I want to know how to animate by changing constraints. Not sure what your answer is for though

Comment: well you said you don't want the label hidden and you said the score is on the label , but the only way the label will get updates is if the square is hidden which (contains the label?)

Comment: if you really want to quit frustrating yourself you should start with what you know works and then move forwards. You know that your touch event is received; if it were me I'd comment out the if statements and start with updating the text without them and then move forward. The above code is a direct copy and paste from a tiny program I just wrote, it works flawlessly and nothing disappears or constrains to objects that from previous constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
 [self.squareOne setCenter:position];
```

You are animating the position of `squareOne` by setting its *position*. But meanwhile you also have *constraints* that also position `squareOne`. That fact remains concealed until you change the text of the label; that triggers layout, and now the constraints all assert themselves, putting an end to everything else that was going on.

One solution is to animate the position of `squareOne` by *changing its constraints*. Now when layout is triggered, the existing constraints will match the situation because they are the *only* force that is positioning things.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the constraints by hand, you can also have `UIImageView` generate constraints during animation (which does not get broken by a sibling UILabel). Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15242064/327815).