# dynamical view resizing with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a following view hierarchy Main -> Green -> Img

The Green view has the constraints seen in image below

[image]

The Img view has the constraints seen in the image below

[image]

So when I click the Button the frame of the Green is resized, and so the Img view because of the constraints between them.

But I get an error:

> 2015-06-07 20:13:07.653 ZoomInZoomOut[7152:1435937] Unable to
>   simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the
>   constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1)
>   look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
>   (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints
>   and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (Names: '|':UIWindow:0x7fcbd3623630 )>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2015-06-07 20:13:07.655
>   ZoomInZoomOut[7152:1435937] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fcbd347fb60 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fcbd3487f80(20)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fcbd347e3f0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fcbd3487f80]   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7fcbd3480a20 )>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fcbd347dd20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fcbd34889a0(0)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fcbd3481700 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fcbd34889a0.bottom == UIView:0x7fcbd3480a20.bottom>",
>       "",
>       "
>   (Names: '|':UIWindow:0x7fcbd3623630 )>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

The code called when the button is clicked:

```
    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    zoomedView.frame.size.height += 10.0
    zoomedView.frame.size.width += 10.0
    zoomedView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
    zoomedView.superview?.updateConstraints()
}
```

From [Auto Layout Tutorial Part 2: Constraints](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83130/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-2) I know that this error is caused by conflicting constraints. But I didn't add any new constraints in code behind. In storyboard if I resize the Green view, I get a misplaced view which I fix by updating constraints. That is why I'm trying to achieve in code behind, but get the error from above. Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the same answer I wrote here should solve your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30687856/3149796

Comment: @Patrick Lynch How to mark your comment as answer?

Comment: I am adding view programatically , so Partrick's answer is not for this case