# How to move a UIView programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, move

The issue is to move an "InfoView" (UIView) programmatically in Swift.

The following constraints exist in the storyboard (see image):

[image]

Now, I would like to move the "InfoView" inside "MyView" up or down.

I tried:

```
@IBOutlet weak var infoTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var infoTextLabelView: UIView!

// set infoTextLabel color
self.infoTextLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
// set infoTextLabel text
self.infoTextLabel.text = "hello"
// unhide infoTextLabel
self.infoTextLabel.hidden = false

// For the moving in Y-direction, I tried this - but does not work !!!!!!!
self.infoTextLabelView.frame.origin.y += 200
```

Could the Autolayout-constraints play a role. How to overcome those programmatically. Or is the frame.origin.y method the wrong one ??

Appreciate any help on this !

Comment: Are you attempting to create an animation or are you just trying to move the view's position w/o an animation sequence?

Comment: There is no need for an animation!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When using constraints, you never want to set a view's frame directly. Instead, reconfigure the constraints and let the auto layout engine set your view's frame for you. Create an IBOutlet in your view controller to store a reference to your "Center Y Alignment constraint". Make sure you connect it in your storyboard or xib.

```
@IBOutlet var yConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint
```

Then you can set the constraint's constant property to offset it from the Y position (positive number will move it down, negative moves it up).

```
yConstraint.constant = 200
```

This would move your view 200 points down.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 17):

See my answer to this other question about a good way to programmatically move views using auto layout:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687856/3149796

Also, depending on the effect you're going for and other requirements of your UI, you might also achieve this with transforms without disturbing your auto layout.

```
// Create a new transform
self.infoTextLabelView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 0.0, 200.0 )

// Or modify existing transform
self.infoTextLabelView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate( self.infoTextLabelView.transform, 0.0, 200.0  )
```

Comment: Make sure you turn off the AutoResizing constraints or the second option doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, dan m.  To this day, both examples appear to work as intended.  Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: 7), animations: {
       self.infoTextLabelView.frame.origin.y+=200

},completion: nil)
```

Comment: what is rawValue: 7 means?

Comment: Swift 5 - UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: 7), animations: { self.infoTextLabelView.frame.origin.y+=200 },completion: nil)

Comment: Or even something simple like this ?: UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                self.formSV.frame.origin.y += 100
            }

Comment: This works for me with the same result: UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, animations: {
            
           self.infoTextLabelView.frame.origin.y+=200

        },completion: nil)

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5**

Use CGAffineTransform

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainCurtain: UIView!

func moveUp() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options:[], animations: {
        self.mainCurtain.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
}


func moveDown() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options:[], animations: {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        self.mainCurtain.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: screenSize.height * 0.5)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```