# Resize a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, resize, frame

I have a Tableview with above it a Segmented Controller. Based on a previous user action, this segmented controller is either hidden or shown.

If it's hidden, I'd like to resize my tableview, so that it looks nice (else I have an empty gap on the screen).

[image]

I tried the following code (placed in the ViewDidLoad) but it did not work. It also didn't work when placed in the ViewDidAppear or other functions. The Tableview is referenced from the Storyboard, its not programmatically created.

```
    if selectedGroup == 1
    {
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 320, 367)
        segControl.hidden = false
    }
    else if selectedGroup == 2
    {
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 116, 320, 403)
        segControl.hidden = true
    }
```

I tried some other stuff like working with offsetting the frame and then adjusting the height, but that didn't work either...

Comment: you are using autolayout?

Comment: No im not using auto layout

Comment: Check the answer if you are not using autolayout then set autoresizeing from utilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess was that you were using AutoLayout. Changes to view frames often don't have any effect in that case. Have you double-checked to make sure it's turned off for you storyboard?

Failing that, the most likely cause of changing having no effect is broken outlets. Add a println to display self.tableView (or set a breakpoint and examine it from the debugger) and make sure it's not nil.

BTW, using constant values for your sizes ("magic numbers") is a bad idea. That code will only work on a single screen size, and will break if you make any changes to your layout.

You should write your code to be flexible. Calculate the frame based on the size of the view controller content view, or the previous frame size.

Comment: I'm an idiot, AutoLayout WAS on... thanks for making me do a double check.

Answer (score 1):

### With Autolayout

If you are using Autolayout and if you want to change the frame then try the constraints (`IBOutlet` of `NSLayoutConstraint`).

[image]

Set the constraint outlets and change `constant` value by :

```
self.sampleConstraint.constant = 20
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

### Without Autolayout

Use autoresizing form utilities

[image]

You can also do it by code (obj-c) :

```
view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |    
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, turns out I did have AutoLayout turned on, my original code works after turning it off... sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @TheNiers Oh, Ok. no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. If you want to use auto-layout but still have the ability to resize certain views on runtime, you can call viewDidLayoutSubviews. This gets called after all constraints are placed, but before the viewDidAppear is called, so the user doesn't even notice

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if catswitch == "1"
    {
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 320, 367)
        scMatur.hidden = false
    }
    else if catswitch == "2"
    {
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 116, 320, 403)
        scMatur.hidden = true
    }
}
```

See [Can I disable autolayout for a specific subview at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368440/can-i-disable-autolayout-for-a-specific-subview-at-runtime) for original answer by jmstone.