# Xcode 7.3 is excruciatingly slow when loading Storyboard IB

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard

I recently upgraded to Xcode 7.3. I found that loading up the storyboard can take anywhere from 5 to 10 minutes to complete(and may sometimes result in a crash). I've restarted my Mac several times. I uninstalled Xcode and reinstalled it to no avail. I then cleared my Derived Data as well as com.apple.dt.Xcode to find that this did not help either. Is anyone experiencing a similar issue and possibly has a solution?

Comment: File a bug with Apple. Send them a copy of your project so that they can debug. Try downgrading to prior version of Xcode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report for a specific product.

Comment: This question is on topic: [“software tools commonly used by programmers”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Xcode is commonly used.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. IB is super slow in this build, changing a single attribute value is painful. Sorry I haven't found a solution yet

Comment: dasblinkenlight, I have followed your advice on this and since downgraded to a previous version of Xcode.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem since I upgraded to 7.3 yesterday.  Simply changing the hidden property of a UIButton takes 30 seconds now.  Screen recording here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uB5VvXEv0_U

Comment: I installed a second copy of Xcode (7.2.1) to test and the same storyboard file works fine.  Really hope Apple comes out with a patch soon.

Comment: Try disabling internet access before loading the storyboard. It worked for me. Not to say this is a solution, it’s a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

Although this actually might be an issue with incremental changes in Storyboards with Xcode 7.3 you can always **speed up build times** by creating **multiple small Storyboard files in favor of a big bloated Storyboard**.

Xcode can then reuse already built Storyboards in subsequent builds (as long as they are not changed) instead of *building the complete bloated Storyboard over and over again* even for small changes.

Apple even **has a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/RefactorStoryboard.html)** that might help getting this started.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I have a single XIB with just a single view in it and it takes around 10-20 seconds to load.  Every single interaction e.g. tapping on the "add constraint" button, positioning/resizing a view takes multiple seconds.  Not entirely sure what's happening but OP is not alone

Comment: Ok so I split everything into multiple storyboards. I still have the issue of just "add constraint" button taking as long as 30 seconds to open up on some views.

Answer (score 4):

This is really annoying bug/issue with XCode 7.3. So, If you have an hour or so to spend you can download and install XCode 7.3.1 Beta from here https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
It seems that this issue has been fixed in this version (at least it works for me).

Edit: OK. After a few minutes, Interface Builder became extremely slow again. Changing only one property can take up to 15-20 minutes.
After some research I have figured out that autolayout constraints were the cause of this issue, BUT only if you have a combination of some components present. **I had a segmented control inside a navigation bar. When I removed navigation bar and placed segmented control in a simple UIView, all issues were gone and IB was smooth again.**

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and had the same problem. My problem was solved by disabling source control. 
Go to **Xcode->Preferences->Source Control** and then **Uncheck the Enable Source Control**. Worked for me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the storyboard gets slow because of unresolved errors of autolayout. In my case i tested by changing screensizes and it showed me some errors on different sizes. Once i resolved those errors the storyboard was working fine. Please confirm

Answer (score 1):

Yep I had the same problem. In design mode, it's Autolayout that is causing the 5-10 second delay between edits, especially if it's a large storyboard. Turning off Autolayout in the storyboard at design time fixed the issue for me:

Open project 
Select storyboard from the Project Navigator
Open the file inspector
Under Interface Builder Document uncheck 'Use Autolayout'

If you need Autolayout at run time, I recommend you layout your Storyboard in design time with this off (to avoid those long delays between edits) then turn it back on afterwards. Or, turn Auto layout on programatically. Or better yet, split your storyboard out into smaller storyboards.

Referenced this question: [Can I disable autolayout for a specific subview at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368440/can-i-disable-autolayout-for-a-specific-subview-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue recently after I updated the OSX to 10.11. Xcode 7.3 will take almost 5 mintues to respond when I just change the button's font (or anything else change). This made me almost crazy. Incidently, just for a try, I updated Xcode from App Store to 7.3.1. Then I was happy to cry when I opened the storyboard and changed the attributes. Xcode responds smoothly.

So please try Xcode 7.3.1 for your problem. Hopefully you can be happy with it.

Comment: It is not working for me. I disabled source control but no effect. :(